# How to use 'explain and suggest' in passive form?

Tags: passive-voice, indirect-objects

Would anyone please tell me which of the following two expressions is correct?

> A. The problem was explained to the children.
>   B. The children were explained the problem.

or

> A. A meeting place was suggested to us.
>   B. We were suggested a meeting place.

Waiting for your kind reply .
Thank you very much .

Comment: What makes you think one is correct and one is not?

Comment: I once read that "if you mention a person after explain, you always use to: 'Let me explain the problem (to you) again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The pupils were explained everything to by the teacher](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189749/the-pupils-were-explained-everything-to-by-the-teacher)

Answer (score 3):

Only the direct object of the verbs "**explain**" and "**suggest**" can be at the head of a passive sentence. The indirect object in the passive comes after the verb.

- The problem was explained to the children. (**Correct**)
- <s>The children were explained the problem.</s> (*Incorrect*)
- A meeting place was suggested to us. (**Correct**)
- <s>We were suggested a meeting place.</s> (*Incorrect*)

For structural analysis:

- The problem *[direct object]* was explained *[verb]* to the children *[indirect object]*. *(Somebody explained the problem to the children. - **Active**)*
- A meeting place *[direct object]* was suggested *[verb]* to us *[indirect object]*. *(Somebody suggested a meeting place to us - **Active**)*

> There are other verbs they work the same way: **announce**, **repeat**, and **describe**.

Comment: I wouldn't say that #2 and #4 are incorrect with *explained*, just less common.

Comment: @Lawrence Are we talking about good grammar or bad grammar? In good grammar they are incorrect, period!

Answer (score 0):

In each example, you're giving one instance in which the *direct object* ('the problem' or 'a meeting place') is the focus, and another instance in which the *indirect object* ('the children' or 'us'/'we') is the focus.

**It is possible for passive structures to begin with either the *direct object* or the *indirect object*.**  Consider these examples:

- The gold medal was awarded to Sue.
- Sue was awarded the gold medal.

or

- The alphabet was taught to the students.
- The students were taught the alphabet.

In each case, both variations are equally strong - it simply depends on which noun you'd like to focus on within your context.

**The problem is that some passive sentences sound awkward when lead with indirect objects - ones linked with verbs such as 'explain' and 'suggest'**.  "The children were explained the problem," and "We were suggested a meeting place," may be colloquially acceptable, but their meanings are not immediately understandable.

Unfortunately, there's not a clear distinction between which verbs are ill-suited for their indirect objects to take the focus of passive sentences, but here's a nice rule-of-thumb:

> In an active sentence, if prepositions such as 'to' can be removed from before the *indirect object*, that *indirect object* can work well as the focus of a passive structure of that same sentence.

- The parents explained <s>to</s> the children the problem. - *removing 'to' doesn't work well.*
- Richard suggested <s>to</s> us a meeting place. - *removing 'to' doesn't work well.*
- The judges awarded <s>to</s> Sue the gold medal. - *it's an okay sentence without 'to'!*
- The teacher taught <s>to</s> the students the alphabet. - *it's an okay sentence without 'to'!*

Just as 'explained' and 'suggested' need 'to' or some similar preposition to come before their *indirect objects*, starting the passive forms with 'the children' and 'we'/'us' respectively creates awkward sentences.  (Just remember that while we're focusing on the *indirect objects* here, it's the verb that determines how they can be used.)

**All that said, it's always acceptable and correct to use the *direct object* at the start of a passive sentence.**  You can't go wrong with "The problem was explained to the children," or "A meeting place was suggested to us."

Comment: The children were explained the problem is agrammatical. To explain something to someone. Not to explain someone something. Very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply:

A. The problem **was explained to the children** [by the teacher]. [passive voice]
B. The teacher **explained the problem to the childre**n. [active voice]

or

A. A meeting place **was suggested to us** [by the teacher]. [passive voice]
B. The teacher **suggested a meeting place to us**.

There you have two sentences in their active and passive voices, with the changes introduced to make them make sense.

the verb explain: explain + direct  object + to with indirect object + by [passive agent]
the verb suggest: suggest + direct object + to with indirect object + by [passive agent]

Answer (score -5):

Both are correct, but they have different meaning.
The first sentence means that the children were explained the problem by someone. 
The second sentence means that the children themselves was explained the problem to someone.

The first sentence is a passive past sentence, while the other one is an active past sentence form.

Comment: -1. This is completely incorrect. Both are passive sentences, and they mean the same thing (that someone explained the problem to the children), just with different foci. Additionally, “The second sentence means that the children themselves was explained the problem to someone” makes no sense whatsoever in English. It is ungrammatical and gibberish.

Comment: I think your statement is correct. Both are passive sentences, and they mean the same thing (that someone explained the problem to the children).